# Was The One Ring the only ring of power with an inscription?

Tags: the-lord-of-the-rings, tolkiens-legendarium

In *The Lord of the Rings*, Sauron's The One Ring has an inscription in it.  It's revealed by exposing the ring to fire.  The inscription describes the ring's purpose and power.  However, this was not the only Ring of Power that was forged.  The Elves made 3, 9 were made for humans, and 7 were made for Dwarves.  Did these rings also have inscriptions?

Comment: The rings were manufactured before labeling regulations required poetic, riddle-like warnings.

Comment: @JohnO "Made in Eregion" ;)

Comment: I've never read anything indicating they did or didn't, and the brief descriptions in the book did not mention them. However, they of course were not exposed to fire and so that is inconclusive. One major difference was that the elven rings at least had jewels set in them, so they were different in some way than the one ring

Comment: Gandalf was hoping it was a cheap knock-off power ring, which would've had an inscription like the one in Bored of the Rings.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As far as we know, [no other ring was inscribed](http://greenbooks.theonering.net/questions/files/090101.html#inscriptions)

Note that all rings were made by the Elves *for their own usage*, it is Sauron who gave them to the other races to corrupt them.

The Elves' ones, the only which were saved from Sauron, were the more powerful ones and the only adorned with jewels. The others were mere prototypes and the fact that they had different effects on Man or on Dwarves is due to each race particular nature rather than to any deliberated design.

Comment: "The Elves' ones, the only which were saved from Sauron, were the more powerful ones and _the only adorned with jewels._" From _The Fellowship of the Ring,_ Book II, Chapter 2, "The Council of Elrond:" "The Nine, the Seven, and the Three,’’ [Gandalf] said, ‘‘had each their proper gem. Not so the One." All 19 of the Rings of Power made by the Elves had gems.

Answer (score 5):

Taking other forms of fantasy and spellmaking, Inscriptions are commonly used to bind a spell to an item (considered an incantation that, by being written, persists).

Since the other rings were rings of power in their own right, it stands to reason that those rings would have inscriptions as well to designate and bind their powers to them.

I, of course, have not found any canonical explanation for this, but it would make sense given the generally accepted notion of magical inscriptions.